# Using a projection in place of observed mean for a poisson distribution

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, poisson

Let's say we have a a theoretical prop bet (where you have the choice to bet *over* or *under* the given number) that, say, Tom Brady throws 40.5 touchdowns in the upcoming football season. This would be a good application of a poisson distribution and satisfies assumptions. So, we write a quick python script to create a poisson distribution using a lambda of 50 (Tom Brady's touchdowns per year for the past 10 years in our theoretical example)

```
from scipy.stats import poisson
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

# prop value and the mean for our distribution
prop = 40.5
mean = 50

# generate Poisson distribution by drawing 100k variates with mean 50 
x = poisson.rvs(mu=mean, size=100000)

# viz
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,5))
sns.kdeplot(x)
kdeline = ax.lines[0]
xs = kdeline.get_xdata()
ys = kdeline.get_ydata()
ax.vlines(prop, 0, np.interp(prop, xs, ys), color="red", ls=":")
```

We can then use the cdf to find the probability of Tom Brady *"hitting the over"* or exceeding 40.5 touchdowns in the upcoming season

```
1-poisson.cdf(k=prop, mu=mean)
0.913929999882039
```

This is a good start, but can definitely be improved by taking into account other data to update this initial value (can we call that 91% a "prior"? I'm not formally trained in statistics...) such as strength of schedule, age, roster changes, and other factors after the fact (using processes that are besides the point of this question).

Ultimately, the question I have, however, is regarding the validity of *not* using past observed data for the mean of the distribution, but rather a projection (incorporating the variables in the previous paragraph) that is created using a machine learning model, monte carlo simulation (etc.). Let's say our model gives Tom Brady a projection of 48 touchdowns for the upcoming season, and we will use that in place of the 50 we used based on his observed mean.

```
# cdf
new_mean = 48
1-poisson.cdf(k=prop, mu=new_mean)
0.8616872800730739
```

Is using a projection for the mean of a poisson distribution as opposed to an observed mean statistically valid? Or does it violate anything? Should projections and poisson models be two separate entities, with the initial probability/prior being updated post hoc for the latter? (does a gamma distribution play into this somehow when incorporating a projected mean?)

Comment: Interesting question, but it is about statistical modeling, not programming, so it is not a good fit for stackoverflow.  A better place for this question is [Cross-validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Apologies. I posted it there https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/587215/using-a-projection-in-place-of-observed-mean-for-a-poisson-distribution. Thanks for the heads up.